# VirtualMachines lost after VirtualBox update

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I recently update my VirtualBox to the newest version and all of a sudden my virtual machines are gone from the main vbox console.
The VirtualBox/HardDisks/vdis & VirtualBox/Machines/xmls files are still there and the 2 settings "Default Hard Disk Folder" & "Default Machine Folder" still point to the right folders.
I could probably delete all the machine files and re-create all the machines using the existing hard disks files but I was wondering if there is any other easier solution like import them in?
And why these setting are not preserved when installing a newest version? The later is more like a rethorical question, I can live without knowing the answer.

Comment: quite an annoyance indeed, that's why i always postpone VBox updates until they roll out a major improvement over previous releases. :)

Comment: You should use the normal channels to contact the VirtualBox people if you run into bugs. The issue you observed wasn't ever reported by anyone else, and it is definitely not the right behavior. Given that 10000s of users upgrade very early this is really unexpected, and if you'd report it with the necessary details it would be investigated.

Comment: I just had the same issue that I described in http://superuser.com/questions/80192/how-to-recover-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox/767208#767208

Answer (score 2):

look for ~/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml

The GUI reads the list of machines from there. I had a similar problem and it turned out it was now looking at /root/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml so i just copied the xml file from my home directory to folder in /root/